# Reaction between phosphorus(III) bromide and alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

Alcohol acts as a nucleophile in a reaction with $\ce{PBr3}.$ It attacks the $\ce{PBr3}$ leaving $\ce{Br-}$ behind. The alcohol forms a bond with the $\ce{PBr2+}.$ How the oxygen having three bonds makes the hydrogen more acidic?

Comment: Think of $\ce{H3O+}$.

Comment: You may also realize that the $\ce{P}$ atom "prefers" to make a $\ce{P-O-H}$  bond than a $\ce{P-Br}$ bond, because $\ce{P-O}$ bond dissociation energy is bigger ($\pu{351 kJ/mol}$) than $\ce{P-Br}$ ($\pu{272 kJ/mol}$)

Comment: @Maurice Can you please explain about it further? I could see the logic in your answer but a deep explanation would be better to understand more clearly.

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26996/why-does-phosphorus-tribromide-act-as-a-lewis-acid-electron-acceptor ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51891/does-halogenation-by-phosphorus-tribromide-lead-to-an-inverted-product/51894